# How do I specify a stylesheet in child-theming WP twentyseventeen? What do I need to do to register my chosen child theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

After some trial and error, it appears that I have created a child theme of twentyseventeen, as I earlier did of twentysixteen, but while the dashboard shows the name I chose for my theme, the stylesheet loaded is not displaying my changes because I modified the child theme style.css and it is loading the original twentyseventeen.css; the rendered pages include `<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyseventeen-style-css'  href='https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css?ver=4.7' type='text/css' media='all' />`.

How can I modify my child theme so it uses its own instead of the parent theme's stylesheet?

My functions.php reads:

```
<?php
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://cjshayward.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://cjshayward.com' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

So far, every thing I've tried has failed to get it to load from its own stylesheet, `/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-ux-tweaks-child/style.css`. Editing `functions.php` hasn't worked. Editing `header.php` hasn't worked, **although I'm wondering if there's some secondary damage because I haven't told it canonically to use my child theme rather than the twentyseventeen original. Replacing `get_template_directory_uri()` with `'/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-ux-tweaks-child` hasn't worked. I could probably get what I want by an Apache URL rewrite, but I'd really like to know the *right* way to do this in Wordpress.

What do I need to register a child theme correctly so that it uses the provided child theme's style.css as its stylesheet?

Thanks,

**--UPDATE--**

My functions.php now reads:

```
<?php
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://cjshayward.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://cjshayward.com' );

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
     $parent_style = 'twentyseventeen';
     wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() .
       '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-ux-tweaks-child',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

I am experiencing the same behavior as before. I have not yet seen `https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/theme/twentyseventeen-ux-tweaks-child/style.css` from inspecting elements and tracing the stylesheets.

Comment: have you inserted the comments in the header of the child theme stylesheet, containing child theme and template name?

Answer (score 1):

According to wordpress.org it's necessary to enqeue both the parent style and the child theme style, so that should be:

```
<?php
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://cjshayward.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://cjshayward.com' );

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'twentyseventeen'; 
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-ux-tweaks-child',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that should be it. I just didn't insert insert the names of your particular themes, but I just edited that.